# Как объяснить значение выражения "ведь воруют"?

Tags: семантика

Как объяснить с точки зрения русского языка, что фраза "Ведь воруют" не означает, что воруют поголовно все?

Comment: Нужно знать контекст. Дайте хотя бы предшествующую фразу.

Comment: Человек утверждает, что по правилам русского языка смысл фразы "Ведь воруют, много воруют" (из Берегись Автомобиля) заключается в том, что воруют все. И ссылается при этом на безличные предложения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Спасибо за сайт и оперативность, с которой появляются отклики! Набралась терпения ждать дольше, а всё произошло почти молниеносно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Все** воруют или не все, может следовать **только** из контекста, *предшествующего* данному утверждению, приводимому в качестве аргумента в пользу уже сказанного. Например:

> Абсолютно **все** люди плохи. Ведь воруют. (= воруют **все**)
>
> На этих двоих надо заявить в полицию. Ведь воруют. (= воруют двое)

В изолированном же виде исходное предложение содержит всего два смысловых элемента:

a) утверждение "воруют" (неизвестно кто ворует, но явление имеет место);

б) упоминание "ведь" (~= сами знаете), означающее, что собеседник сам должен бы знать о том, что *кто-то где-то* ворует - совсем не обязательно, что "все".

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Поняла абсолютно, благодаря примерам. Явление имеет место быть. И в данном случае - неважно кто его осуществляет!

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, кому вы объясняете. Проще всего, наверное, подобрать аналогичное выражение с более понятным/привычным собеседнику смыслом. Например, утверждение "ведь эти книги читают" не означает, что их читают все поголовно.

Comment: Спасибо! интуитивно понимаю, но не смогла разобраться со смыслом в безличных предложениях

Answer (score 0):

В отсутствие контекста "Ведь воруют" может бытъ понято как угодно: "Ведь все воруют", "Ведь многие воруют", "Ведь некоторые воруют" и т. д. Поэтому его нельзя рассматривать абстрактно. Сравните: "Ведь разводятся". Никому в голову не придет, что разводятся все.